# Is there a way to render one component of a page in server side in React applications

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, server-side-rendering

I have my react application and back end services running in a kubernetes cluster. I want my react application to access one end point by passign the API gateway. ( Withouts user login in)

Is there a way to use kuberentes internal cluster communication instead of going through the API gateway to fetch data only this perticular component before sending the page to the client.

I dont know how to implement this in React. But I can access my end points from React pod using the following url. http://..svc.cluster.local:/’

Comment: If the request is made server-side (ie as part of SSR) then yes, you should be able to use the internal DNS

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [server-side APIs](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server) in React to do the server rendering of the components. There are React frameworks that build with SSR capabilities like Next.js, Remix, and Gatasby. If you have a React App bootstrapped using create-react-app then it is just client-side rendering on your hand ATM. But you can extend it to have SSR features using a simple Node.js server. I suggest you move to a framework which already has SSR features.

Regarding your question related to k8s,

You should use a `ClusterIP` type service to expose the backend internally for serving SSR requests from the backend. The traffic flow for an SSR request and response will flow in a high-level view as below:

[image]